# Block IP in Google Cloud Instances

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

I want to deny the ssh login for the IP address permanently in firewall  from which the user tried the SSH more than 3 times  in the GCP instance.

Also the blocked ip address details should get as an email to the admin user . Is this possible through GCP ?

Answer (score 0):

An [ingress](https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/firewalls) rules with a `deny` action to a specific protocols and ports or even better deny all ports option can be used to block incoming traffic from the offending external IP address; However, access is not denied after the offending user has tried to access the VM instance more than 3 times and failed, either will it auto-block the IP and email the admin user. So, this is not possible with GCP firewall.

However, it may worth checking intrusion prevention software such as "[FAIL2BAN](https://www.fail2ban.org/wiki/index.php/Main_Page) etc".

> Fail2ban scans log files (e.g. /var/log/apache/error_log) and bans IPs that show the malicious signs -- too many password failures, seeking for exploits, etc. Generally, Fail2Ban is then used to update firewall rules to reject the IP addresses for a specified amount of time, although any arbitrary other action (e.g. sending an email) could also be configured. Out of the box, Fail2Ban comes with filters for various services (apache, courier, ssh, etc).

Fail2Ban is able to reduce the rate of incorrect authentications attempts however it cannot eliminate the risk that weak authentication presents. Configure services to use only two factor or public/private authentication mechanisms if you really want to protect services.